# Reverse scrolling direction every time i use a different app

Tags: mac, macos

I'd like to reverse my scrolling direction every time i use a different app (i use a regular mouse). For example, when i use Chrome or the OS in general, i want my scroll direction to be set "natural".

But when i use Photoshop i want my scroll direction to be the other way. I've installed an app which sits in my menu bar and i can quite easily (without going into settings) change my scroll direction. But if i have to do this like 50 times a day it's quite annoying.

Is there a way that every time i'm using photoshop, my scroll direction changes automatically?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this with [Karabiner](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/). Among other things, you can use it to reverse your scroll weel. It has some presets for this already, but if there isn't an exact match, you'll have to modify private.xml file to make custom settings.

There's [samples.xml](https://github.com/tekezo/Karabiner/blob/master/src/core/server/Resources/include/checkbox/samples.xml) file, that contains pretty much an exact example of what you are after. It flips the scroll in Safari:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <item>
    <identifier>remap.samples_flipscrollwheel</identifier>
    <name>Flip Horizontal and Vertical ScrollWheel at Safari</name>
    <only>SAFARI</only>
    <autogen>
      __FlipScrollWheel__
      Option::FLIPSCROLLWHEEL_HORIZONTAL,
      Option::FLIPSCROLLWHEEL_VERTICAL,
    </autogen>
  </item>
</root>
```

- You'll probably want to check out [how to make custom settings](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/document.html.en#privatexml).
- The
  scroll wheel flipping is not documented yet, so if you want to find more samples of that, you gotta search the [samples.xml](https://github.com/tekezo/Karabiner/blob/master/src/core/server/Resources/include/checkbox/samples.xml) for `__FlipScrollWheel__`
- Documentation on [how to specify an application](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/xml.html.en#appdef)